# Plotting a function defined to be infinite over a sub-domain

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I'm trying to plot the following function with the constraints shown,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \infty \quad x<0 \\ A\,x\quad x\ge 0 \end{cases}$$

However I can't work out how to show this in *Mathematica*, I tried using `RegionPlot[]` but it doesn't seem to work (or I'm missing something!). The other way I thought of would be to plot as two separate functions and then use `Show[]`.

If someone has a smarter way that would be helpful!

Comment: how do you want to represent the infinite value of the function for $x<0$?

Comment: On the plot it would just have to 'look' large. In reality I would just set to a high value and tweak the plot range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Piecewise` is built for exactly this purpose:

```
With[{a = 2, inf = 100},
 Plot[
  Piecewise[
   {
    {inf, x < 0},
    {a x, x > 0}
    }
   ],
  {x, -2, 2}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{2.0, x < 0}, {x^2, x > 0}}], {x, -1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 Mesh -> {{2, 0}},
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {Dashed, Automatic},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {1, {2, \[Infinity]}}},
 TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is also a great solution, thanks for the contribution!